# Multiply two columns with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to multiply two columns with [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables). I have my table this way:

```
<table border="5" class="teste1" method="POST" id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="filter" style="width:42px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px">Quantidade</th>
<th class="filter" style="width:25px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px">Preço</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
?>
<td style="font-size: 12px"> <?php echo $rows_cursos['Quantidade']; ?></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px"> <?php echo $rows_cursos['Preco']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>';
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Then I'm trying to multiply the column of the `quantity * price` as follows:

```
(function ($) {$(document).ready(function () {
$('#table').dataTable({  
drawCallback: function () {
  var api = this.api();
  $( api.table().footer() ).html(
    api.column( 1 * 2 ).data().sum()
  );
}
});
})(jQuery)
```

But it is not working, and I want to show the data in a row at the bottom of the table, in the `<tfoot> </ tfoot>` table. I intend that the sum of this multiplication always returns the result according to the filter.

Comment: Should those be sum of each quantity multiplied by each price or price times quantity per row?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg  must be the sum of the quantity multiplied by the price and not by the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you have your HTML prepared by PHP-script (which is not the best available option, in my opinion).

Howerver, if you have some node within your `<tfoot>` reserved to display total cost (let it be `span#sumproduct`, for instance), you may:

- get visible ([`{search:'applied'}`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) selector modifier) rows source data into array with [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) and [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)
- reduce that array into total cost
- refresh `span#sumproduct` [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) each time you get your footer re-drawn ([`footerCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback) option):

```js
//source data
const srcData = [['apple',5,3],['pear',4,2],['banana',3,1]]

//datatables initialization
$('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'ft',
  data: srcData,
  columns: ['item', 'qty', 'price'].map(title => ({title})),
  footerCallback: function(){
    const sumProduct = this
      .api()
      .rows({search:'applied'})
      .data()
      .toArray()
      .reduce((res,[item, qty, price]) => res += qty*price, 0);
    $('#sumproduct').text(sumProduct);
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script></head><body><table id="example"><tfoot><tr><td colspan="3">Overall cost is: <span id="sumproduct"></span></td></tr></tfoot></table></body></html>
```

Comment: I edited the question with the code changed according to your answer, but I get an error. 

Can you help?

Comment: You don't need to care about that, just skip `data` and `columns` options within `DataTable()` constructor. Also, if there are just 2 columns (quantity and price), you'll need to change `[item,qty,price]` for `[qty, price]` inside `.reduce()` arguments.

Comment: You're confused with [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You may do `.reduce((res,row) => {const qty = row[4], price = row[8]; return res += qty*price},0)`